# Do you have to use objectWithID when the instance variable is already retrieved?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Below in asyncReloadAndMoveToEnd, we reference conversation which is an instance variable.

In order to access the conversation.messages, do we need to be retrieving that object via the objectID via a separate managed context.

```
- (void) reloadTable {
    [self.tbl reloadData];
}

- (void) asyncReloadAndMoveToEnd {

    // is this the right way since it's in a separate thread?
    NSArray* messages = [conversation.message allObjects];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void) reload:(bool) inMoveToEnd {

    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(asyncReloadAndMoveToEnd)
                                                                              object:nil];

    [queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

Comment: Your code looks wonky. Is there a typo? Did you mean to say `@selector(reload)` instead of `@selector(reload:)`? `reload:` calls `asyncReloadAndMoveToEnd` asynchronously (of course), then `asyncReloadAndMoveToEnd` calls `reload:`, also asynchronously by performing it on the next iteration of the main thread run loop. It seems like it will bounce back and forth. Since it looks like a chat application, maybe that's what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch ManagedObjects for display in a UITableView, [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is strongly recommended. It handles storage, caching, and all of the general heavy lifting.Ray Wenderlich has a great [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) on  its use.

Comment: Thanks for the message.  I may have to eventually resort to something like that.